# Why is there no GLES option in GPU Frame Capture in xcode edit scheme

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl-es, metal

I was trying to capture a gpu frame of an MAC openGL program (https://github.com/JohnTargaryen/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp) using xcode. The camera icon used to capture frame didn't show up when i ran the program, so I did as the link below suggested, meaning to change GPU Frame Capture to GLES. However, there is no GLES option for me to choose.
[no GLES option in GPU Frame Capture in xcode edit scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0yE5.jpg)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/frame_capture_debugging_tools/enabling_frame_capture?language=objc

What's the possible cause and how I can solve it? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has deprecated OpenGL ES in iOS 12, the XCode GPU tools now only support the Metal API.

Also, OpenGL-ES is not available on MacOS, only OpenGL, which is also deprecated.

See the warning mention for example in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

> **Important** OpenGL ES was deprecated in iOS 12. To create high-performance code on GPUs, use the Metal framework instead. See [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/).

For OpenGL, a similar warning mention is [visible](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html) :

> OpenGL was deprecated in macOS 10.14. To create high-performance code on GPUs, use the Metal framework instead. See Metal.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but first of all, the original question is refering to a MAC OS program instead of an IOS APP, and secondly, I have another IOS APP that runs on OpenGL ES backend that has OpenGL ES option available in Edit Scheme->Run->Options->GPU Frame Capture

Comment: Ok, it would be nice to edit your question and tags accordingly then, as you specified iOS. Also AFAIK OpenGL-ES is not available on MacOS, only OpenGL, which is also deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. I think this solve my question.
"OpenGL-ES is not available on MacOS, only OpenGL, which is also deprecated."